# Modernizr bunch of errors

Tags: syntax-error, modernizr

I'm currently looking into modernizr (modernizr.com) and when I look at the source in an IDE, I get a bunch of errors on line 813 such as:
-Function created in a loop
-Undeclared variable
-Missing semicolon
-Expected ")"
-Etc...
I just wanted to know if this is normal/a fault of the IDE because it appears to be functioning normally. You can see the source, copy pasted from [here](http://modernizr.com/download/#-fontface-backgroundsize-borderimage-borderradius-boxshadow-flexbox-hsla-multiplebgs-opacity-rgba-textshadow-cssanimations-csscolumns-generatedcontent-cssgradients-cssreflections-csstransforms-csstransforms3d-csstransitions-applicationcache-canvas-canvastext-draganddrop-hashchange-history-audio-video-indexeddb-input-inputtypes-localstorage-postmessage-sessionstorage-websockets-websqldatabase-webworkers-geolocation-inlinesvg-smil-svg-svgclippaths-touch-webgl-shiv-cssclasses-addtest-prefixed-teststyles-testprop-testallprops-hasevent-prefixes-domprefixes-load)

Answer (score 0):

Was just a weird IDE bug in c9.op turns out the code has no problems!